# Expected an identifier and instead saw '*'. (E030) [jshint]

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jshint

I'm making a function in which I need the square root of a number.
The problem is that when I try to use the exponentiation operator "**"
Visual Studio Code gives me the error:

```
"Expected an identifier and instead saw "*". (E030)"
```

The operation still works so I'm wondering why does it even give me an error.
I compared it to the Math.pow function and it gives the same result.

```
let xDist= (x2-x1)**2;
let xDist= Math.pow ((x2-x1),2);
```

Comment: JSHint has pretty poor support of modern js. https://www.slant.co/versus/8627/8628/~jshint_vs_eslint

Answer (score 2):

I think you are hitting the issue of jshint not supporting exponentiation operator yet!
For now, you can ignore the line with a trailing comment like this:

`let xDist= (x2-x1)**2;  // jshint ignore:line`

Refer: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/2602